# What is the default value for the --user-data-dir argument for VSCode on macOS (or other OS's)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue with VSCode that seems to get fixed if I specify a custom `--user-data-dir` argument. So I'd like to figure out what file in the user-data-dir is causing my issue. Or at least just delete my entire user-data-dir. Where can I find the default user-data-dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new command in Insiders Build v1.75 now (and presumably in the Stable Build in early February, 2023):

```
Developer: Open User Data Folder
workbench.action.openUserDataFolder
```

that will open your user data folder in your OS's file explorer so you can see where it is located by default and what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The path you're looking for is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code
```

or

```
/Users/YourName/Library/Application Support/Code
```

If you delete this folder it will be as if you provide a completely new `--user-data-dir` argument.